# google map not loaded after signing the application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am too much confused. My google map application works fine before signing the application. After signing the app the map not loaded and grey screen still showing. I search this problem whole day and apply every answer find in stack overflow and also other sites but failed to load the map. also apply this method:
[Signup and API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

please help me.

Comment: You need to use your own **Keystore** certificate file and not the default one.

Comment: I generate my own keystore using android studio and then generate sha1 using cmd but map is still grey..

Comment: did you generate sha1 with the new certificate you created ?

Comment: Yes i done this in cmd as mention in question method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem, follow the instruction.

After you get the new SHA-1 key after signing the application, go to your google developer console.

There in your **existing** API key which you created,  Edit the sha-1 key and save it, by this your api key will remain same.

After this **DO NOT RUN THE APP AGAIN FROM YOUR ECLIPSE/ANDROID STUDIO IDE, as it will launch the app with old sha1-key**

**Install the signed apk in your device**, by this your app will request google with the signed apk sha-1 key.

Comment: then it definitely means ur sha key problem, definitely is, read my steps again, i had exact ditto same problem

Comment: Logcat shows in debug mode.. It chnge my sha1 with debug mode (default sha1) and api key on my console is with my keystore sha1...how to check logs in release mode?

Comment: just plug your device, run the app(not from IDE) and see logs, you need to give the signed sha1 vesion in your google dev console(in the api section)

Comment: Yes give signed sha but logcat shows the old one while the key is new in logcat... And logcat not show in release mode or only device is attached

Comment: do like this, after u sign ur app you get an option to export the apk right ? get that apk and install it in your device, and tell me if u get the map. Keep in mind that ur dev console should have the released app's sha key

Comment: I generate keystore in android studio. using this keystore i generate SHA using cmd and set this sha in google console to generate api key then use this key in my project. after that i set my android studio to auto generate the release apk file. the attach my cell with adb set build variant to release and install app directly on cell.... map is not loading and there is no logcat when i select release build variant.

Comment: bro, did you get just the .apk file after doing generate signed apk ?

Comment: yes i generate the signed apk build>generate signed apk using android studio. but how can i see logs of the apk in log cat?

Comment: i do not know why your logs are not coming, but just folow this now, now get your generate signed .apk and install it in you phone, remove all wire connections, just follow me, we will make it work

Comment: I send signed apk using bluetooth and install it but map is not loading.. in logcat under my device name there is no debugable app...

Comment: ok, good, now go to your google dev console, and check if the sha-1 key is same as the one which you got after signing it

Comment: after signing i have no sha1 i generate it using my keystore in CMD using keytool -list -v -keystore this method and set it in dev console... during signing the app i use same keystore file..

Comment: ok see, after you signed you app you must have signed it by your_keystore_name and your_alias_name; now in your command prompt run keytool -list -v -keystore <your_keystore_name> -alias <your_alias_name> with the required parameters, you will get the relased sha1 fingerprint

Comment: yes i already done this all before signed the app.. in CMD i get sha1 which i use in dev console to generate api key

Comment: bro after u sign the app you will get different sha1 key

Comment: here is the signed log....Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE

Comment: read this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html, you will know what i am trying to tell

Comment: it is impossible to get same signed sha key after doing signed version

Comment: if this is possible then what is the problem? I generate sha before signing the app and then signed the app with the same keystore...i there some thing wrong? i have keystore in different directory and app source in different directory...

Comment: bro, it is no way possible that your debug and release app will have same sha key, you probably will be getting a blank google map with google logo in left bottom, your app has got a different sha key, I am 100% sure

Comment: But i also tried the sha that is generated my keystore and the same keystore i used when signing the app... then what is the problem now.. logcat why not show the api key..

Comment: upload your code to bitbucket or github and send me the link, il check it or send it to androidappsnexus@gmail.com, il check it

Comment: can you tell me.. the name of keystore can be different with the name of app?? or any other name need to match?

Comment: the name of the keystore will be given by you, it is not name of the app, you give name of the keystore while signing it

Comment: i try to add .keystore extension with my keystore but it says file not exist then i use it without this extension..is there anything wrong ?

Comment: your steps are wrong. read the steps http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html very very carefully, just read it once, your answer is here

Comment: which api key insert in my code before the signing ?

Comment: the api key you get before signing is default key, you need to get release key, please read the blog link which i gave you in comments

Comment: which key are u talkng about ? release or debug or api ?

Comment: bro, after you get api key, you dont have to set it again in manifest, you just need to update the release sha1 key in the google dev console

Comment: bro, this chat is becomming too long, please try it by yourself

Comment: Solved.....
I get key from Dev Console by enter both SHA (debug and release) same key is generated for both.. I put this key directly into my manifest file not using @string..

Comment: How were you able to get the release sha key ?

Comment: WHY WERE you not able to do that before ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add SHA-1 of signed application on google console with your project package name.

For Android Studio:

Click on Build > Generate Signed APK.

You will get a message box, just click OK.

Now there will be another window just copy Key Store Path.

Now open a command prompt and go to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin> (or any installed jdk version).

Type keytool -list -v -keystore and then paste your Key Store Path (Eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "E:\My Projects \Android\android studio\signed apks\Hello World\HelloWorld.jks").

Now it will Ask Key Stroke Password, provide yours and press Enter to get your SHA1 and MD5 Certificate keys.

Comment: Done this many times... I uninstall the app from my dvice then install it again bt same result..

Comment: For signed apk, you'll not get your SHA1 by above method, mentioned in question.

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes m using Android Studio

Comment: Yes i do same as u mention but map not loading :(

Comment: Authentication failed. Make sure api key is exist. Api Key <your api key>

Comment: Try creating new project on Google console. Again create SHA1, by above procedure and try it. I do think so, that it will be a problem from your side. So, do follow each and every step.

Answer (score 0):

it is because your SHA-1 code generated as Debug key
Debug key:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

you have to get SHA-1 for you **sign key** :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
keytool -list -v -keystore  D:\Android\signkey\prj_name_SignKey\prj_name.jks -alias myalias
```

> Do Not Use Spaces for alias and directories.
>   it gives you different SHA-1 but your Google API_KEY doesn't changes
>   it's so **Simple**
>   Good Luck

Comment: you get new SHA-1 and use it in Google console, Don't You ?

Comment: Yes i do... But map not loading

Comment: Logcat shows authentication  failed... Is the api key exist.... Yes api key is correct and generating using keystore file's sha1 key.. Same keystore is used for signing the app....

Comment: Use correct API_KEY, you can reach it from Google's Console Panel, copy that into NotePad and Make Sure no incorrect characters attached

Comment: please get new API_KEY and launch app again, also please copy LogCat

Comment: Sending API token request.
10-05 14:58:44.800   9919-10765/com.locationreminder.azmizryk.locationreminder E/b﹕ Authentication failed on the server.
10-05 14:58:44.800   9919-10765/com.locationreminder.azmizryk.locationreminder E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): E8:A3:***********C2;com.locationreminder.azmizryk.locationreminder

Comment: did you enable "Google Maps Android API v2" From Google Console's panel ? check it please

Comment: Yes i also make new project and enable it.

Comment: if you enabled the only reason is : your API_KEY is incorrect. if you think any thing is correct please upload sample to check

Comment: Solved.....
I get key from Dev Console by enter both SHA (debug and release) same key is generated for both.. I put this key directly into my manifest file not using @string..

Comment: Well Done , Hope you improve to Advance .

Answer (score 0):

you are using old version of sha1. you need to again generate SHA1 using command prompt after making you apk signed.Steps to regenerate SHA1 is go to cmd and give the command like below:
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore 
   "C:\Your key store path\keystores\android.jks"

go to your java in program file open java version like jre1.8.0 open bin folder and run command like above follwed by your key store path that you have generated when you generated the signed apk